# modify code to post to a function dhtml/java/ajax

Tags: java, ajax, dhtml

Can anyone help changing this code to post to function?
the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9C2g5/

code:

```
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3719 COCOPLUM CIR <br>Unit: 3548<br>COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64638716">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report" class="view_report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3927 COCOPLUM CIR <br>Unit: 35124<br>COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64638744">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report" class="view_report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3949A COCOPLUM CIR <br>Unit: A<br>COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64639105">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report" class="view_report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3949 COCOPLUM CIR <br>Unit: 3602<br>POMPANO BEACH, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64639106">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report" class="view_report">
</form>
</div>
<div id="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="address-wrap">
<div id="report-address">3949 COCOPLUM CIR <br>Unit: 3603<br>COCONUT CREEK, FL 33063</div>
<div id="report-button">
<form action="report.html">
<input name="property-id[]" type="text" class="property-id" value="64639107">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Report" class="view_report">
</form>
```

that post to :

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("input[type=submit]").click(function(e) {
var propertyid = $(this).prevAll("input").first().val();
alert(propertyid);
});    
});
```

the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9C2g5/

how can we change this the right way to post to function ??

Comment: What do you mean by "post to function"?

Comment: to post it like : onclick="quantity('product1');" and script function is like: function quantity(item_id)
{ var propertyid = $(this).prevAll("input").first().val();
alert(propertyid);
 }  ,,,, but this not working, so need to do this the right way

Comment: The fiddle you posted seems to be working. It is showing a correct alert. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: i want to post it to a function instead of $(document).ready(function(e) {
i want it to post like: to post it like : onclick="quantity('product1');" and script function is like: function quantity(item_id) { var propertyid = $(this).prevAll("input").first().val(); alert(propertyid); } ,,,, but this not working, so need to do this the right way

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are looking for (if not, please try to make your question more explicit):

Define a separate function that will be called for each of the buttons.

```
<script>
    function quantity() {
        var propertyid = $(this).prevAll("input").first().val();
        alert(propertyid);    
    }
</script>
```

Then, define each of you buttons as `input` with `type` attribute set to `button` instead of `submit`. For ex.

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="View Report" onclick="quantity.apply(this)" class="view_report">
```

Alternatively, the `quantity` function can be defined as:

```
<script>
    function quantity(element) {
        var propertyid = $(element).prevAll("input").first().val();
        alert(propertyid);    
    }
</script>
```

and the button can be specified as:

```
<input name="submit" type="button" value="View Report" onclick="quantity(this)" class="view_report">
```

The only difference is that with the first way, you can access the target element by using `this`.

However, neither of this is a recommended way. Mixing JS code with your HTML is considered bad practice. You can search google for `Separation of concern` for more information. What you are doing currently is the right way of doing it (a few minor changes might need to be applied, like `replacing` the type 'submit' with type of `button`).

Comment: can you jsfiddle the example?

Comment: When you use it, you can put the function in a separate JS file if you want.